# Bootstrap grid row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

can you help me? I would like create a small image feed. Is it possible without plugin? Enclosed a image from the idea.

I tried it with the bootstrap columns. Can I break the horizontal grid?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 "><img class="masonry" src="#"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 "><img class="masonry" src="#"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 "><img class="masonry" src="#"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img class="masonry" src="#"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img class="masonry" src="#"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img class="masonry" src="#"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img class="masonry" src="#"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img class="masonry" src="#"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Workplace

[image]

#### Idea

[image]

Comment: You could use `float` in your css

Comment: See http://www.bootply.com/1Tq35rlkbx